# Unable to invoke circuit breaker using Spring Cloud Gateway and Resilience4j

Tags: java, spring-cloud-gateway, resilience4j

I am trying to implement a simple circuit breaker with resilience4j and spring cloud gateway.
I am trying to follow **an-only properties configuration** rather than java bean configuration.

I have 2 services and both are successfully registered with the Eureka Discovery server.
Here is my spring cloud gateway yaml file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: LOGIN-SERVICE
          uri: lb://login-fs
          predicates:
            - Path=/login-fs/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: loginCircuitBreaker
                fallbackuri: forward:/loginServiceFallBack
        - id: REGISTER-SERVICE
          uri: lb://register-fs
          predicates:
            - Path=/register-fs/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: registerCircuitBreaker
                fallbackuri: forward:/registerServiceFallBack
                
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
    configs:
        default:
            slidingWindowSize: 100
            permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 5
            waitDurationInOpenState: 10000
            failureRateThreshold: 60
            eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
            registerHealthIndicator: true
            record-exceptions:
             - java.lang.Exception
    instances:
       loginCircuitBreaker:
            baseConfig: default
            waitDurationInOpenState: 5000
       registerCircuitBreaker:
            baseConfig: default
            waitDurationInOpenState: 5000

management:
  health:
    circuitbreakers:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```

I want to invoke the fallback method if an exception occurs within the method(s) mentioned in the  `predicates:`or `- Path=` section of the configuration.

My fallback RestController is as follows:

```
package com.cloudgateway;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class FallBackMethodController {

    @GetMapping("/loginServiceFallBack")
    public String loginServiceFallBack() {
        return "Login Service is taking longer than expected to respond." +
                " Please check back in sometime ";
    }

    @GetMapping("/registerServiceFallBack")
    public String registerServiceFallBack() {
        return "Register Service is taking longer than expected to respond." +
                " Please check back in sometime.";
    }
}
```

**Dependencies in pom.xml :**

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The application runs without any error and the api gateway runs fine (i.e. it is able to route the requests as per the path pattern mentioned, using a common domain and port) but the fallback methods are not triggered when an exception occurs.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is fallbackUri and not fallbackuri. I don't spot any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

change in restcontroller from this  `@GetMapping("/loginServiceFallBack")`  --> to `@RequestMapping("/loginServiceFallBack")`